# How to share Tableau file with SQL connection so that connection is shared also

Tags: sql, connection, tableau-api, share

I have a tableau file that I developed and I need to share it with some coworkers.
The tableau file has data that is pulled from a SQL server.
All of the coworkers who receive the file have access and permissions on the SQL server.

When I share the tableau file via email or through a shared drive the SQL connection no longer links up and the data is no longer populated.

How can I share this file so that the SQL connection is still connected when my coworkers open the file?

The data is live and is too big to share as a packaged workbook or to upload to the tableau server.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can publish a live connection to a dataset to Tableau Server. With the correct permissions, others can now use it in worksheets.

Comment: Thanks @matt_black.
So it will share the actual connection to the SQL server, as opposed to having to upload all of the data from the SQL server to the Tableau server?

Comment: Yes. And you can embed permission if appropriate or force the user to log in to the data source when that is safer. Tableau server is fairly flexible, allowing refreshable extracts or direct connections to data sources.

Comment: Thank you! @matt_black